# Поместить Title страницы в Input - WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Необходимо поместить заголовок страницы в текстовое поле. Каким JS или PHP скриптом это можно сделать?

Comment: Заголовок страницы в WP вызывается так: `<?php the_title(); ?>`

Comment: Нужно поместить заголовок в Input поле.

Comment: Ну так поместите его в input `<input type="text" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">`

Comment: Если это, что вам нужно, отметьте, пожалуйста, мой ответ решением

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заголовок страницы в WP вызывается так:

> `<?php the_title(); ?>`

Чтобы поместить его в `input` :

> `<input type="text" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">`